# Fortran runtime error: End of file when reading input data

Tags: file-io, fortran, eof

I'm currently running a code and I'm always getting to the same end. I am trying to read an input file and it returns the error:

> Fortran runtime error: End of file

In an other post they said to put in the iostat specifier so now my code looks like this:

```
INTEGER    :: m
INTEGER    :: st

Open(Unit = 13,action='read',file='Data_Inp.dat',status='old')
read (13,*, iostat = st) m
write (*,*) st
write (*,*) m

ALLOCATE(winkel(m),energie(m))

Do i = 1,m
  read(13,*),winkel(i),energie(i)
End Do
```

And the input file looks like this:

```
12
-17.83 -0.019386527878
-15.83 -0.020125057233
-12.83 -0.020653853148
-11.83 -0.020840036028
-9.83 -0.020974157405
-8.83 -0.021056401707
-6.83 -0.021065517811
-5.83 -0.020992571816
-4.83 -0.020867828448
-1.83 -0.02069158012
```

Now the terminal prints a -1 for iostat and a constantly changing number for m.

Comment: Which other post is that?  In general, using `iostat` doesn't magically prevent an error, it just allows you to handle it rather than have the runtime terminate.

Comment: Okay I got that. But can you imagine, why I get the EOF Error. I can't find a mistake in my input file. The error must be at the read command.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is just your example file not being the real file, but you only have 10 data entries in your example file but your code would try to read 12 lines, this is something that could give you an End of file error.

Comment: Oh no, I tried smaller and bigger numbers than 10 to see if that first entry is the problem but at the end the error was the same. So that's not the mistake. If this would be the cause of the EOF error than the first read command won't cause an error but it does.

Comment: Can you expand on your example to include the program statement, implicit none etc. I was able to successfully compile and run your code when I supplied my open program statement etc. so these details may be important. Note, I do get an EOF error but only inside the loop, when i>10.

Comment: The symptoms described can be explained by the program not finding the input file when it runs.  You are probably sure that it is in the right place, but appropriate use of the `inquire` statement might confirm, or deny, your belief.

Comment: You can get additional information by printing the iostat value in the loop     `read(13,*,iostat=st),winkel(i),energie(i);  write (*,*) i,st`

Answer (score 1):

If the first read command is causing an error, check for extraneous characters before or after "12" in your input file, especially if you created it on one platform (Windows?) and using it on another platform (Linux? Mac?)

Comment: your answer looks like a comment.